# Which privilege is required to truncate data in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want my php file user to be able to `truncate`.  In phpmyadmin there is an option to set privalage to `DROP`, but I can't see one for `TRUNCATE`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It requires the DROP privilege as of MySQL 5.1.16. (Before 5.1.16, it requires the DELETE privilege).

Answer (score 6):

truncate It requires the `DROP` privilege as of MySQL 5.1.16. (Before 5.1.16, it requires the `DELETE` privilege).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html

Answer (score 1):

you would need a DELETE privilege.

Comment: Or from 5.1.16 onward, `DROP`

Comment: Sure. I always said that DELETE was not the right choice, since it resets auto-increments sometimes, which is not allowed by DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific TRUNCATE privilege. See the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html):

> TRUNCATE TABLE empties a table completely. It requires the `DROP` privilege as of MySQL 5.1.16. (Before 5.1.16, it requires the `DELETE` privilege).

Answer (score 1):

As per the MySQL manual's [TRUNCATE syntax page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html):

"TRUNCATE TABLE empties a table completely. **It requires the DROP privilege as of MySQL 5.1.16**. (**Before 5.1.16, it requires the DELETE privilege**)."

Answer (score 1):

"TRUNCATE TABLE requires the DROP privilege as of MySQL 5.1.16. (Before 5.1.16, it
requires the DELETE privilege."

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html